# Errors when deploying to Heroku [logs included]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm having trouble deploying to Heroku, I've just fixed a postgresql error but now have an ActionView error amongst others. Not sure how to fix this one. please advice.

the git for the blog: https://github.com/Apane/Blogit_blog

Heroku Logs

```
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="right1">
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= login_required class: "actions", id: "new_blog_post_link" do %>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <%= link_to t(:new_blog_post, scope: 'blogit.posts'), new_post_path %>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.941979+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered blogit/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (91.1ms)
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (unknown attribute: name):
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946665+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/blogit/posts/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_blogit_posts_index_html_erb__3752095678148312245_34603300'
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: </div>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <% end %>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.997684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:32:07.997684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-05-25T02:32:10.467911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-05-25T02:37:19.248690+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-05-25T02:38:02.467323+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy de08b17 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:38:02.493201+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by "email"
2013-05-25T02:38:02.544564+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy de08b17 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:38:03.445329+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-05-25T02:38:04.208989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-05-25T02:38:06.350047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 41915`
2013-05-25T02:38:07.613671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:38:08.321413+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:08] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:38:08.321413+00:00 app[web.1]:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-05-25T02:38:15.184606+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:38:15.184606+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:38:15.187273+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:38:16.758556+00:00 app[web.1]: [Blogit]: Blogit::Configuration#rss_feed_language has been deprecated. You can remove this from your blogit.rb configuration file
2013-05-25T02:38:17.431528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:38:17.431823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-05-25T02:38:18.932239+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:18] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-05-25T02:38:18.932504+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=41915
2013-05-25T02:38:18.932239+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-05-25T02:38:19.138465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-25T02:38:19.286419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-05-25 02:38:24 +0000
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:41915
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-05-25T02:38:24.865680+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Blogit::PostsController#index as HTML
2013-05-25T02:38:25.061058+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered blogit/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (130.6ms)
2013-05-25T02:38:25.061376+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 196ms
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (unknown attribute: name):
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="right1">
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-springs-1056.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=407ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= login_required class: "actions", id: "new_blog_post_link" do %>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <% end %>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <%= link_to t(:new_blog_post, scope: 'blogit.posts'), new_post_path %>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: </div>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/blogit/posts/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_blogit_posts_index_html_erb___1859728747634219045_31435420'
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
2013-05-25T02:39:31.009984+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by "email"
2013-05-25T02:39:35.228241+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: Awaiting client
2013-05-25T02:39:35.254224+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-05-25T02:39:36.715005+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-25T02:39:43.583619+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: Process exited with status 0
2013-05-25T02:39:43.598693+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: State changed from up to complete
2013-05-25T02:47:44.635791+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 3b2c0e0 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:47:44.659753+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by "email"
2013-05-25T02:47:44.704699+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 3b2c0e0 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:47:45.205793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-05-25T02:47:48.591029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 27123`
2013-05-25T02:47:49.862664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:47:50.836497+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:50] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:47:50.836497+00:00 app[web.1]:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-05-25T02:47:54.610704+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them 
in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:47:54.611109+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:47:54.611344+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:47:56.472610+00:00 app[web.1]: [Blogit]: Blogit::Configuration#rss_feed_language has been deprecated. You can remove this from your blogit.rb configuration file
2013-05-25T02:47:57.907795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-05-25T02:47:57.907795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:57] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-05-25T02:47:57.908723+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=27123
2013-05-25T02:47:58.197066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-25T02:47:58.851641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:47:58.851887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:27123
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-05-25 02:48:00 +0000
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-05-25T02:48:00.290164+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Blogit::PostsController#index as HTML
2013-05-25T02:48:00.460839+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered blogit/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (98.8ms)
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="right1">
2013-05-25T02:48:00.461055+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 171ms
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (unknown attribute: name):
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <% end %>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <%= link_to t(:new_blog_post, scope: 'blogit.posts'), new_post_path %>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= login_required class: "actions", id: "new_blog_post_link" do %>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: </div>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/blogit/posts/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_blogit_posts_index_html_erb___1549385033592403810_36478100'
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:48:00.463077+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:48:00.471980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-springs-1056.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=421ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-25T02:48:01.026129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Comment: Did you run a DB migration? `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Thanks Jim - yep, I've migrated the db and have installed postgresql and unicorn server. i'd like to hear any other suggestions or thoughts that you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your problem. In schema.rb you have

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

and in User.rb you have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name

  blogs

  def username
    name = "Anthony Panepinto"
  end

end
```

you need to delete the `username` method and run a `migration` to add `username` as an attribute of `User`

```
rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string
```

then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you did this right your `schema.rb` will look like this

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.string "username"
end
```

and `User.rb` should look like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name

  blogs

end
```

You want to do all this locally in the development environment to make sure everything is right before you push it to Heroku. Its easier to debug in development first rather than looking at Heroku error logs.